# Are validators still options on buildSchema in Type Graphql?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to figure out how to define an ApolloServer using graphql and express (trying to follow the lireddit tutorial published by Ben Awad).

Currently, I'm trying:

```
const schema = await buildSchema({resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver, UserResolver], validate: false })

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(schema)
  // ({
  //   schema
  //     // schema: await buildSchema({
  //     //   resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver, UserResolver],
  //     //   validate: false
  //     }),
      
      // context: (req, res): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em.fork(), req, res }) - per Mikro ORM example
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({ em: orm.em, req, res })
  });
```

The commented part shows the process in the tutorial. The same error message is returned on the validation point.

I have lots of errors, but isolating them and tyring to solve them individually, one of them is that I can't use validate:false on the buildSchema options.

The error message says:

```
Argument of type '{ resolvers: [typeof HelloResolver, typeof PostResolver, typeof UserResolver]; validate: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BuildSchemaOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validate' does not exist in type 'BuildSchemaOptions'
```

The [docs](https://typegraphql.com/docs/validation.html) for type-graphql suggest that validate is a valid option.

Comment: Which package is `buildSchema` imported from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';